# navigation parameter page view with react-swipeable-views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have a page that displays a list of exercises and when you click each name it brings up a description and you can log your exercise. Going to each page is done by passing the navigation parameter.

On all react-swipeable-views demo it shows that within that page you have to have a link to each page on top of the code. But the issue I'm running into is that I am going to each page by passing the navigation parameter.

Right now this is how I'm displaying all of the exercises that clicking on them goes to the page with all of the logging capabilities.

```
  <View style={styles.CenterContent}>
                        {exerciseHistories && exerciseHistories.map(exercise => (
                                    <StartedWorkoutCard onPress={() => this.onPress(exercise)}>
                                        <Text style={styles.HOneTitles} >{exercise.name}</Text>
                                        <Text style={styles.WorkoutSet} >{`${exercise.completedSets}/${exercise.sets} Sets Completed`}</Text>
                                    </StartedWorkoutCard>
                        ))}
```

how can I use this with `react-swipeable-views`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-native async-storage for that. Param that you want to send another screen using react-swiplabe-views firstly u have to store param to to async storage using `set` method and you can get those data using `get` method in componentDidMount() or useEffect(). For more information use following official doc for react-native async-storage.

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/